# What is the return usage in onsubmit event handler in this code

Tags: javascript

I don't know why return is used again in `onsubmit` event handler in this code?
`return` has been used twice in this code.
First in js function (the function `return false` to invoker)
Second in `onsubmit`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
   var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
   if (/*x == null ||*/ x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `return false` ensures the post is not submitted to the server given x is empty.  What exactly is your question?  By `return`ing false you stop the post such that the `fname` field is filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return `false` from an `onsubmit` event handler, this will prevent the submit of the form to the server from happening. So basically this will propagate the return value of the `validateForm` function to the `onsubmit` handler.

I would also recommend you updating your `validateForm` to ensure that you always return a boolean result, not only in the negative scenario:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (/*x == null ||*/ x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    // In this case we return true and allow the form to be submitted.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the function returns false to onsubmit if input fname is null or empty string so the answer of onsubmit is false, so why we need to return false to onsubmit (do you mean only when onsubmit = return false it prevents posting to server but when submit= false it posts, Am I right?)

Comment: Yes, exactly, the `validateForm` function returns false in this case. So you should make sure that you propagate this result to the `onsubmit` handler by using `return validateForm()`. Also as I suggested in my answer you should take care of the positive scenario by returning true as well if the form values are valid.

Comment: The `return true` at the end is not needed at all. The HTML5 spec defines that if the code inside event handler attributes returns boolean `false`, then the event should be cancelled. Other values are ignored.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's not needed but this doesn't mean that we should write crappy code. I find it completely horrible to have return statements in one portion of a function and not in other. Maybe it's because I am coming from strongly typed languages background in which such abuses aren't allowed. Unfortunately it's exactly because of such horrible things that the javascript language allows that we end up with this: http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/02/22/javascript-the-weird-parts/ That's why I adore TypeScript - it wouldn't allow you such monstrosities.

Comment: I totally agree with you about coding style. It's just the comment above the return that bugs me, because it states that the return true is required.

Answer (score 0):

The return false ensures the post is not submitted to the server given x is empty. What exactly is your question? By `return`ing false you stop the post such that the `fname` field is filled out.

Answer (score 0):

One return is inside of the function to actually return value. Another return is inside of `onsubmit` attribute to pass it along, so the form can act on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` inside the `validateForm` function defines the return value of the function.
The one in `onsubmit` attribute defines the return value of the whole event handler. For most event types, if the handler returns boolean `false` (there are several exceptions to the rule), then the browser should interpret that we want to cancel the event. In case of `submit` event, cancel means not submit the form.

[HTML5 spec about event handler attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes:event-mouseover)